# Getting the postion of the y-axis labels in chartJS

Tags: typescript, chart.js, aurelia

I have a ChartJS area and sometimes the data is so much that the y-axis labels are slanted. I have two issues with this.

1. How can we make it go 100% vertical so I can increase the grid lines and they don't overlap?
2. How do I get the bottom point of the label?

For the label point, I am able to get the y-axis bottom point like so:

```
 const yBottom = chart.scales['y-axis-0'].bottom;
```

I have the following screencap:

[image]

I want to get the bottom of that label.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make x-axis tick labels 100% vertical by defining option `scales.x.ticks.minRotation: 90`.

```
options: {
  scales: {
    x: {
      ticks: {
        minRotation: 90
      }
    }
  }
}
```

> For further information, please consult [Tick Configuration](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/cartesian/category.html#tick-configuration) from the Chart.js documentation.